# How to get typeArgs from a type in M7?

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, scala-2.10

I am migrating some code from Scala *2.10-M5* to Scala *2.10-M7*. I have found that the Type API in the macro context has been notably reduced. In particular, I am wondering how to get the **underlying** and **typeArgs** defs.

--

**UPDATED**

As requested by @EugeneBurmako, I am going to show the whole picture. Suppose we have this state:

```
class Attribute[C[_], E]

class Id[E]

trait Entity {
  val att1: List[Int]
  val att2: Int
}

object Entity {
  val att1reif = new Attribute[List, Int]
  val att2reif = new Attribute[Id, Int]
}

def Let[T <: Entity, C[_], E](en: T, att: Attribute[C, E], ce: C[E]): T =
  /* Updates the whole attribute */

def Let[T <: Entity, C[_], E](en: Entity, att: Attribute[C, E], e: E, mode: Boolean): T = 
  /* Adds or removes (mode) an item */
```

where we have an *Entity* hosting some attributes. The entity companion object contains meta-information (reifications) about those attributes. The *Let* family allows updating the entities (by creating new copies).

So far, so good. We can use the Let methods as follows:

```
val ent = new Entity { val att1 = List(); val att2 = 3 }
Let(ent, Entity.att1reif, List(1, 2, 3)) // att1 = List(1, 2, 3)
Let(ent, Entity.att1reif, 4, true)       // att1 = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
Let(ent, Entity.att1reif, 1, false)      // att1 = List(2, 3, 4)
```

The reification attribute is redundant, so we'd like our users to have a simpler API. In particular, the next one:

```
// Same code as DSL
ent.att1 := List(1, 2, 3)
ent.att1 :+ 4
ent.att1 :- 1
```

Notice that there isn't information about the reification anywhere. So, we need some *Helpers* and a macro view to reach our goal.

```
trait AttributeHelper {
  type T <: Entity
  type C[_]
  type E
  val ent: T
  val att: Attribute[C, E]
  def :=(ce: C[E]): T = Let(ent, att, ce)
  def :+(e: E): T = Let(ent, att, e, true)
  def :-(e: E): T = Let(ent, att, e, false)
}

def toAttributeHelperImpl[V: c.AbsTypeTag](c: Context)(expr: c.Expr[V]): c.Expr[AttributeHelper] = 
  /* A looong macro (currently broken), since I can't split V into C[_] and E,
   * which are needed to generate the expression that instantiates an *AttributeHelper*.
   * The macro is responsible of finding the attribute reification.
   */
```

Our macro definition is, in fact, a view, and it does the magic to allow the DSL expression:

```
implicit def toAttributeHelper[V](expr: V): AttributeHelper = macro toAttributeHelperImpl[V]
```

I have been trying to go on with a macro which uses two type params, but while doing so, the implicit view is not applied (because the compiler can't infer both types).

So, as I mentioned at the beginning, the lack of *typeArgs* which was available in M5, but does not in M7, has broken the previous macro. How can I generate the AttributeHelper construction without having that def?

Finally, I must say that the previous code is just a simplification. There are some other involved evidences, that's why I need to use the *underlying*.

Comment: Could you please provide examples: 1) an example of the incoming `T`, 2) what you want to get as a result of `typeArgs`, 3) what you want to get as a result of `underlying`.

Comment: If I missed something, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea behind the reflection API cleanup, which happened somewhen around M5, was to remove extremely specialized methods.

For example, `typeArgs` is only applicable to `TypeRef` types, so it doesn't make much sense to keep it in the base type `Type`. The replacement is a simple pattern match: `tpe match { case TypeRef(_, _, args) => arg; case _ => Nil }`.

`underlying` is different, though, since it's an internal implementation concept that means a lot of things depending on a concrete flavor of the type. If you elaborate on your use case, I might help with finding an alternative for `underlying`.